# Android Compose SideEffect

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What's difference between these 2? one using SideEffect, the other doesn't.
"SideEffect is invoked on every successful recomposition", but without SideEffect, it is also run on every recomposition.

```
@Composable
fun BackHandler(
    backDispatcher: OnBackPressedDispatcher,
    enabled: Boolean = true, // Whether back events should be intercepted or not
    onBack: () -> Unit
) {
    val backCallback = remember { /* ... */ }

    // On every successful composition, update the callback with the `enabled` value
    // to tell `backCallback` whether back events should be intercepted or not
    SideEffect {
        backCallback.isEnabled = enabled
    }

    /* Rest of the code */
}

@Composable
fun BackHandler(
    backDispatcher: OnBackPressedDispatcher,
    enabled: Boolean = true, // Whether back events should be intercepted or not
    onBack: () -> Unit
) {
    val backCallback = remember { /* ... */ }

    backCallback.isEnabled = enabled

    /* Rest of the code */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The difference is in the term "successful". The effects of a call to  `BackHandler` are not guaranteed to be part of the resulting composition even if it is called (there ways it can be discarded are rare and difficult to describe). `SideEffect` ensures the lambda is only executed if they are.

A `SideEffect` ensures that,

1. It is only applied when the effect of the enclosing scope is actually part of the resulting composition.
2. It is called after the composition has been realized into the resulting composition (that is the `LayoutNode`s have been created and successfully inserted into to the layout tree). This is important internally (for things such as focus) but might not have that much application outside the framework internals.
3. It is a separate snapshot than was was taken for composition and any observable changes will affect the next composition, not this one.
4. It is always called on the applier's thread (that is the Main thread for `LayoutNode`s).

Only (1) above is relevant here.

It is considered bad practice for a composable function to have a side-effect not encapsulated by `SideEffect` or similar construct as doing so breaks the assumption that composable function are referentially transparent with respect to the composition.

Comment: Thanks. I only understand #1, the compose “engine” internal maybe complex and hard to understand, but maybe I will have better understanding of #2, #3. To a user of compose, how the internal work maybe not relevant anyway